# How can I decide error 'Incorrect integer value: '\FEFFN' for column 'id'' if id field is with AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql

I create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
          `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `txt` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
          `col4` enum('case1','case2','case3') DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And I try to load data from file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:/mysql/test_folder/data.txt'
INTO TABLE tbl1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

data.txt:

```
\N,test1,2023-10-26,case2
\N,data_test,2023-10-26,case2
\N,test1,2023-10-26,case3
\N,data_text,2023-10-26,case1
```

And I get error:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '\FEFFN' for column 'id' at row 1
```

How can I decide this problem?

Comment: 'Restrictive data interpretation uses these rules:...Assigning NULL (that is, \N) to a non-NULL column results in an error.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html consider Input Preprocessing in the same man page

Comment: @P.Salmon, what can I do to load data with auto_incriment id field without error? By the way, I am studying by youtube lessons and there is without error, like this, of the teacher

Comment: ??You are trying to load null (\N) to auto_increment and there is no guarantee that you have set up your server the same as the youtube lesson server. You should read the manual page and throw away the \N column as described therin